# JSON Schema: Element is valid based on another element's value

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate a json schema based on the relation between two elements of the json object.

According to the draft of JSON Schema: to validate elements a json with inter-depedant keywords:

> 4.2.  Inter-dependent keywords
>
> In order to validate an instance, some keywords are influenced by the
>   presence (or absence) of other keywords. In this case, all these
>   keywords will be grouped in the same section.

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor9

My problem is that the draft, doesn't really say how to write the schema in order to provide that validation. What I need to do, is validate a json like this:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2}
```

When a is always lower or equal to b. Can this be done? How do I write the schema?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What that part of the spec means is (for instance) that the `"additionalItems"` keyword's behaviour depends on the `"items"` keyword, so the two keywords are placed next to each other in the spec.

Unfortunately, this kind of comparative validation of two values is not possible in JSON Schema.  All the value constraints are calculated independently.

Comment: Hi - small update on this one.  The next version of JSON Schema (v5) might have a new keyword: [`$data`](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/%24data-%28v5-proposal%29).  This keyword would let you do exactly what you want - so it might be worth keeping an eye on the progress of v5, which is hopefully soon! :)

Comment: No problem - when the draft actually comes out, I'll update my answer. :)

Comment: Damn... I was really hoping this would be a thing. The docs weren't getting me anywhere fast. I guess you can infer from the lack of something being documented that it's not a feature :) But when in doubt, there's always SO. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: FYI, draft 5 has been published... Although probably best to wait for draft 6. If the docs are still missleading in draft 5, please come file an issue on github =]